# Fast Numerical Approximation to system of non-linear equations

Tags: numerical-methods, systems-of-equations, nonlinear-system

I am currently looking into Halley's Method. However, I wanted to see if there were better methods to solve the problem I am looking to solve.

Fast means a low number of iterations in my case. Also, due to the limitations of my processor, I would need to simplify the equations to additions, multiplications, divisions, and powers (also roots).

All capitalize letters are constants.

$XJ^2 = 2V\widehat AJ + \widehat A^3 + \widehat D^3$

$\widehat D^2 = VJ + \widehat A^2$

$y^2 = VJ + A^2 + AJx$

$X = \frac{2VAJ + A^3}{J^2} + \frac{3A^2 + 2VJ}{2J}x + \frac{A}{2}x^2 + \frac{2VJ + 2A^2}{J^2}y + \frac{2A}{j}xy - \frac{1}{J^2}y^3$

I am trying to solve for $x$ or $y$, where $x > 0$ and x is in REALS. $\widehat D \neq D$ and $\widehat A \neq A$.

I have tried the substitution method and the aid of WolframAlpha to solve for the solution. The solution is often time are way too long or Wolfram does not recognize my query.

Again, I am looking for a fast numerical method to solve my problem (mainly the last 2 equations) -- solve for x or y.The approximation threshold for $x$ is about 1E-11 based on empirical calculations.

Comment: On the one hand you say that capital letters are constants, and on the other hand you mention the "result of X". So is X a variable or a constant?

Comment: I am sorry about the confusion. X is a constant.

Comment: You can eliminate $x$ in terms of $y^2$ using the 3rd equation, plug it into the 4th equation and then you have 4th order polynomial in $y$